# How to troubleshoot "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: baseUri"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-cloud-platform, google-api-dotnet-client

I need help diagnosing this error.  Others get it on various platforms (youtube, for example) but seems not solved for most of them.  For those who do report success, their solutions haven't work for me.

I'm using Google Drive API and I receive this error when attempting to upload to Google Drive.

My code was working fine for a long time; suddenly, I get this error.  After research, I determined that I haven't reached a quota, and that these API are enabled:

- Debuglet Controller API
- Drive API
- Google Cloud Dataflow API
- Google Cloud Dataproc API
- Google Cloud Deployment Manager API
- Google Cloud Deployment Manager V2 API
- Google Cloud Storage
- Google Cloud Storage JSON API
- Google Compute Engine Autoscaler API
- Google Compute Engine Instance Group Manager API
- Google Compute Engine Instance Group Updater API
- Google Compute Engine Instance Groups API
- Google Container Engine API
- Google Machine Learning API

Here's my code:

```
        string fileName = @"c:\temp\MyPicture.jpg";
        string fileTitle = @"TEST-DELETE-ME.jpg";
        string fileDescription = @"Test file name";
        string fileType = "image/jpeg";
        string parentId = "zmzmzmzmzmzmzmzmzmz";

        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService service = (Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService)Service;

        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
        body.Title = fileTitle;
        body.Description = fileDescription;
        body.MimeType = fileType;
        body.Parents = new List<ParentReference> { new ParentReference() { Id = parentId } };

        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, fileType);

        Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress = request.Upload();

        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = request.ResponseBody;

        if (file == null)
        {
            //Here we are, and we shouldn't be!
            //progress.exception.message = 
            //
            //Value cannot be null.
            //Parameter name: baseUri
        }
```

When I look at Drive API settings, these are the configurations:

- No icons (there are boxes to set 256x265, 128x128, 64x64, 32x32, and 16x16 all are blank)
- The application name and short and long descriptions are all blank and optional.
- For Drive Integration, all boxes and checkboxes are blank or unchecked.  Specifically:
- "Automatically show OAuth 2.0 consent..." is unchecked.
- "Open URL" is blank.
- Default and secondary MIME types and file extensions are blank
- "Allow users to create new documents..." is unchecked
- "Allow users to open multiple files..." is unchecked
- "Allow users to open files that can be converted..." is unchecked
- "This application can be launched and works properly in a mobile browser" is unchecked.

Users don't use the Google Drive UI to create documents via my application, and is not meant to be used on a mobile browser.  My application only uploads PDF files to users' accounts.

My application has been working for months with no problems, now suddenly seeing this error.

I have tried disabling all API's and then re-enabling them.  No dice.

I have tried using a new client id and secret.  No dice.

I have tried using a new gmail address and creating a new client id and secret.  No dice.

I can't possibly be the only person in the world with this problem.  Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: I'm using this library as well but for Google Cloud Storage.  I have encountered two (thus far) exception situations which result in this ambiguous error message.  If the client is not properly authenticated, and I try to upload a blob, I get this "baseUri" exception.  If I am attempting to upload to a bucket that does not exist, I get this "baseUri" exception.  It's likely that you are doing something like this for google drive (not sure what equivalent situations would be for Drive, but surely they exist.)  I do, however, get proper error messages when attempting to retrieve blobs...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Anj.  In my case, my code allows to log in, navigate folders, and upload or download a file.  The download works fine, it is the upload that fails.  So the folder exists and authentication works.  I should mention that the code hasn't changed, although the code worked at one time.  That is why I provided the details that I did; someone suggested that my API permissions weren't configured correctly.

Comment: Added Google-Cloud-Platform tag in hope to expand reach out to other developers.

Comment: That error looks like it is being generated by the .NET client itself, not the Drive API. Please include a full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Stack Trace:

at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.<UploadCoreAsync>d__e.MoveNext() in c:\code\github\google-api-dotnet-client\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Release\1.9.2\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 460

Comment: InnerException: null

Source: Microsoft.Threading.Tasks

Message: "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: baseUri"

HResult: -2147467261

_COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766

_exceptionMethod = {Void ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)}

Comment: Sorry... wish i could format it better :-(  But, thank you for your help.  I am using .NET 4, and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040921/argumentnullexception-baseuri-is-null-when-uploading-a-file-to-google-drive. If that doesn't help, I would recommend posting an issue to https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues as there may  be a problem with the client library as per @SteveBazyl 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue is like an authorization issue or some other error with the request. However, there's a bug in the .NET client that is masking the error.

See https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/456

Comment: As requested, I provided the stack trace above.  Sorry, I don't know how to format it in this forum, so it doesn't show well.

I should mention that I don't get a runtime error.